# What is the correct way to transfer values between Models in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, transactions, associations

I have the following setup in my app.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :balance, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email
  has_one :account
end
```

Where we have Users (like customers in bank), that have an account. If I would now like to transfer funds from Account A to Account B, what would be the right way to do this in Rails 3?

We were thinking of wrapping the whole statement within transaction, similar to this :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  david.withdrawal(100)
  mary.deposit(100)
end
```

but what is not clear to us is, do we need to create new methods in controllers, or .... basically how would you achieve this, also, would you write a method that simply changes amounts in database, or should we make new methods in controllers that would take care of this. Most importantly, how would you pass variables from forms to models in the right way, given, that form would not always be in the views structure of that specific model.

Then again - maybe there is a gem for this?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a helper method?

Comment: @mdepolli I am not sure, I am quite new to this. I have never wrote a helper yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the same code `mdepolli` posted, just re-organized

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :balance, :user_id
  belongs_to :user

  def withdraw(amount)
    # ...
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    # ...
  end

  def self.transfer(from_account, to_account, amount)
    from_account.withdraw(amount)
    to_account.deposit(amount)
  end
end
```

calling code (controller action?)

```
Account.transaction do
  Account.transfer(david, mary, 100.02)
end
```

depending on your preference you might want to start the transaction block inside the transfer method? I usually push mine out to the controller actions

and here is a slightly modified version using a hash so the calling code can use keys instead of ordered parameters

```
  def self.transfer(args = {})
    from_account = args.fetch(:from)
    to_account = args.fetch(:to)
    amount = args.fetch(:amount)

    from_account.withdraw(amount)
    to_account.deposit(amount)
  end

  Account.transfer({ from: david, to: mary, amount: 100.02 })
```

Comment: Yup, a class method makes far more sense. Vote for this one!

Answer (score 0):

helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def transfer(from_account, to_account, amount)
    from_account.withdraw(amount)
    to_account.deposit(amount)
  end
end
```

models/account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  def withdraw(amount)
    ...
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: code under helpers is meant for helping in the views, rendering html, etc... - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#view-helpers - i would make the transfer method a class method on Account or create a new Transfer object

Comment: Yes, there are usually dozens of different ways to do the same thing in Rails. Feel free to post your code!